# Is the form element "multiline" broken?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create an input field in the Admin Panel where the user can enter multiple values. I stumbled upon the `multiline` frontend type which seems to be perfect for what I'm intending. I added the field to the Admin Panel like so:

**system.xml**:

```
...
<fields>
    <notification_recipients>
        <frontend_type>multiline</frontend_type>
        <line_count>10</line_count>
...
```

But there are two problems:

- After saving the field, the settings from the lines are concatenated in the first field:

[image]

Also, the "line count" argument isn't respected when rendering the field(s), as you can see in the screenshot. I found out about "line count" from **/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Multiline.php**:

```
class Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiline extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
        ...
        public function getElementHtml()
        {
            ...
            $lineCount = $this->getLineCount();
```

So now my question is: Should I avoid using this field type because it's buggy (I could hardly find any references to this field type on the net) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I couldn't find a single reference to the `multiline` frontend type in 1.7! I'd avoid.

Comment: Yes, very strange. I noticed it's never actually used in the core. But it would be perfect for my use case. Too bad. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some more hours of research it seems that this field can't be used reliably.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to out and say that multi line has numerous problems

1. You'll have to define your own backend model to `implode` and `explode` based on your delemiter. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Array` only does the `implode` meaning that saving works okay, but loading fails.
2. It outright doesnt work with the "Update attributes" products mass action. If you don't enter data it will overwrite the field with `Array` even though you were not changing the attribute.
3. Admin actions log will not happily display the values being changed

These things have bit me, and I imagine I will continue to regret using multiline in the future.